# Split data from multiple rows in excel using a delimiter

Tags: c#

I've a windows form with multiline text box. I'm trying to copy paste some data from excel sheet

[image]

I'm trying to split this values and add it to a string array using the below code

```
string[] languageList = language.Split('\n');
```

The output I'm getting is a single string

```
"c#javac++C"
```

instead of 4 strings, ie

```
languageList[0] = "c#"
languageList[1] = "java"
languageList[2] = "c++"
languageList[3] = "C"
```

Is there a way to split the excel row values using any delimiter?

Comment: `"\n"` is the line delimiter for Linux. Windows uses `"\r\n"`. Better to write the code as `language.Split(new[] { System.Environment.NewLine });`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @kaveman, thanks your suggestion worked, I tried out the below code language.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chosen delimiter `\n` is the Linefeed `LF` character, which delimits new lines on Linux-like operating systems.

The delimiter `\r\n` is the Carriage Return + Linefeed `CRLF` character, which delimits new lines on Windows machines.

For the most robust code, use the `System.Environment.NewLine` property, which will pick the correct delimiter *string* based on the environment.

```
string[] languageList = language.Split(new[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Notice the use of `new[] { System.Environment.NewLine }` - this is because when using a string separator with `String.Split()` you must pass it as a `string[]` argument.

Comment: thanks, I will remember this :) :)  Split(new[] { System.Environment.NewLine }); was giving an error message for me, stating sting.split has some invalid arguments. so I tried Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); it worked